How to make a title of procedure over multiple lines with the cryptocode package?
Update: My issue is solved, thanks to Marijn (see the first answer below)! I leave my question below.
I use the package cryptocode to write algorithms, in particular the
\procedure command that I use within pcvstack/pchstack environments. One of my algorithm have a title that is too long for one line, but I don't find a way to break a line and thus write my title in multiple lines.
For information, here is an exemple of simple procedure:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lambda,
            advantage,
            adversary,
            probability,
            operators,
            keys,
            asymptotics,
            sets]{cryptocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{pchstack}
        \procedure[linenumbering]{A title that is wayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy tooooooooooooooooooooooooooo looooooonnnnnnnng}{
            a \sample \bin \\
            \pcreturn a 
        }
\end{pchstack}
\end{document}

that gives, with pdflatex :

I tried to include the title in a tabular environment, like this:
\begin{pchstack}
        \procedure[linenumbering]{\begin{tabular}{c}A title that is wayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy \\
        tooooooooooooooooooooooooooo looooooonnnnnnnng\end{tabular}}{
            a \sample \bin \\
            \pcreturn a 
        }
\end{pchstack}

but it doesn't compile, and indicates:

"Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr"

Do you have an idea to achieve it?
Thanks for your help!

Welccome to TeX.SE! Please show us a TeX code you have used so far!

Thank you!  I updated my question with an exemple of code and of - non working - solution.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Regular linebreaks, i.e., \\ work for the title:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lambda,
            advantage,
            adversary,
            probability,
            operators,
            keys,
            asymptotics,
            sets]{cryptocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{pchstack}
        \procedure[linenumbering]{A title that is\\wayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy\\tooooooooooooooooooooooooooo\\looooooonnnnnnnng}{
            a \sample \bin \\
            \pcreturn a 
        }
\end{pchstack}
\end{document}


However, as you can see the calculation of the length of the horizontal line does not take these linebreaks into account.
To fix that you can put the title in a \parbox where you guess the width yourself (here I used 5cm). Then the parbox will do the breaking for you and the horizontal line will be the width of the parbox:
\begin{pchstack}
        \procedure[linenumbering]{\parbox{5cm}{A title that is wayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy tooooooooooooooooooooooooooo looooooonnnnnnnng}}{
            a \sample \bin \\
            \pcreturn a 
        }
\end{pchstack}


However, now it is justified, and maybe you also want to insert additional linebreaks. You can solve both issues by adding some \\ again:
\begin{pchstack}
        \procedure[linenumbering]{\parbox{5cm}{A title\\that is\\wayyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy tooooooooooooooooooooooooooo looooooonnnnnnnng}}{
            a \sample \bin \\
            \pcreturn a 
        }
\end{pchstack}



Thank you! This completely solves my problem!
